# Grid layout stretching height to fit content, but remaining other grid-cells height

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm trying to make grid layout. This is code:

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="header">HEADER</div>
        <div class="nav">NAV
        </div>
        <div class="aside-left">LEFT</div>
        <div class="main">MAIN
            <img src="a1.jpeg">
            <img src="a1.jpeg">
            <img src="a1.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="aside-right">RIGHT</div>
        <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>
    </div>
</body>

.wrapper{
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   background-color: ghostwhite;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(12,1fr);
   grid-template-rows: minmax(100px,auto);
   grid-gap:5px;
   }
   .header{
       grid-column: 1/13;
       grid-row: 1/2;
   }
   .nav{
       grid-column: 1/13;
       grid-row: 2/3;
   }
   .aside-left{
       grid-column: 1/3;
       grid-row: 3/10;
   }
   .main{
       grid-column: 3/11;
       grid-row: 3/10;
   }
   .aside-right{
       grid-column: 11/13;
       grid-row: 3/10;
   }
   .footer{
       grid-column: 1/13;
       grid-row:10/12;
   }
```

I want class main to stretch to fit it's content and it is working, but `.nav` and `.footer` doesn't take up their min height `100px`, but they seem to take up auto height too, however header class works correctly, so any ideas? I want other elements to have at least `100px` height

Comment: add property min-height: 100px; to the .nav and .footer

Comment: yes, but what if i want nav to strech 2 rows, it doesn't work.

Comment: if i would have been at your place i would not have made grid for this. grid have different use case. in this case flex property would have suffiece the purpose. try doing it with flex.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out answer:

```
body, html{
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    height: auto;

}
.wrapper{
    max-height: auto;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: ghostwhite;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,1fr);
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px,auto);
    grid-gap:5px;
}
```

it seems 100% height was factoring out other elements' height, while increasing others'